# JSOUP extracting multiple elements in the same time

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I wonder if there is any way to extract from a code like this:

```
<div class="container  ">
                      <h2 class="job">
                          <a href="/work/android-developer/madrid/11537332" rel="nofollow" 
                          title="job Android Developer" class="job-offer ">
                              Android Developer
                          </a>
                      </h2>
                          <h3 class="company">
                                  <a href="/emp/nbc/133192">
                                      NBC Corp. 
                              </a>
                         </h3>
              </div>
```

text `Android developer` and `NBC Corp.` in one shot?

Something like `doc.select("h2,h3.p-job-title,p-name-company a[href]");` isn't working. I tried also `doc.select("h2.p-job-title a[href], h3.p-name company a[href]");`

Need help please!

EDIT: I found out that using `doc.select("h2.p-job-title + h3.p-name.company");` I can extract the needed things, but what I need is h2 content + h3 content in one line, I mean "Android Developer       NBC Corp.". This way I got:

"Android Developer"

"NBC Corp."

Comment: Why can't you concatenate the Strings yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Text `Android developer` and `NBC Corp.` in one shot ?

Try this:

```
Elements es = doc.select("div.container"); 

for(Element e:es)
{
System.out.println(e.select("h2").text()+"\t"+e.select("h3").text()); 

 }
```